# How to manually install PHP and Apache in Ubuntu 14.04 without using apt-get

Tags: server, apt, apache2, php, lamp

I'm trying to configure my machine(Ubuntu 14.04) for LAMP but I want to install PHP and Apache HTTP Server the hard way i.e. without using apt-get or any other package manager.
(I've chosen the hard way just to get more knowledge on how these packages get internally connected and work together beautifully).
I've download these packages from their respective sites but having problems while installing and making them work together.
Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.
Please guide me :) .
P.S. I've already downloaded apache and php. Please help me in the further process.

Answer (score 2):

i think you know that you will have to keep track of security fixes and bugs for your LAMP Setup then. Apt would kind of do this for you implicitly.

Well how far did you get then? There should be documentation for each part of your setup like here for php: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php

Learning how to gain knowledge by yourself is imo the most important thing, cause its universal. Imo this makes it more important than how to find out to build your own lamp.

regards

Comment: BTW if you like compiling and choosing compiler flags you might be better off with gentoo linux. :p

Comment: Indeed, there is documentation for each module in LAMP but the problem is how do i connect them to make them work together. Suppose I have php and apache downloaded and extracted on my PC. But now how do I make them work together.

Comment: First you compile the source code of e.g. apache and php (build php as an apache module). Then you configure Apache to use the php-module, like here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php#78781 and nja, just plain google ;) http://www.web-tech-india.com/articles/php/compiling_php_apache/ - more background in wikipedia, ubuntu howtos, etc. - good luck ^^-d

Comment: You will need to install the development tool chain using apt-get, and also back up your /etc/ directory. Then you will need to run configure, make and make install to install the files in the file system from their tar balls.  This will probably fail multiple times  for both packages. You will have to go download dependencies and build those by hand as well.

Comment: Nja you can trick the dependencies by installing a lamp setup with apt and then remove apache, php, etc manually.

Comment: @Lord_PedantenStein good idea! Get the deps or at least the list from apt-get  tar-balls normally install into /usr/local or /opt and so do not conflict with distro packages so probably no need to remove them. Sometimes  settings conflict so back up  /etc/

Comment: Nah its not perfect since you might need the development version of a specific package.

Comment: @Lord_PedantenStein Thanks alot for the clever trick ! :D . Sorry ,but since the answer doesn't directly indicate how should I install the packages manually, it won't be right for me to accept the answer now. I would definitely accept it if you could add some more info to it. Thanks.